# Codeigniter: How to upload more than one file (not input[] array) and return current path to the file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im new to codeigniter and i have a form with 3 input files that i have to upload and get their path , somehow i cant understand how to do it in codeigniter

here is a part of my form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('drivers/create');?>
 ............................
..............................
..............................
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Passport</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="passport" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Driving license</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="driving_license" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Cv</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="cv" value="">
</div>
```

Than in my controller i have 2 functions create() and upload_image() in create function im trying to call upload_image() to get for each input file  path

here is my create()

```
        if ($_FILES['passport']) {
        $passport = $this->upload_image($_FILES['passport']);
    }
    if ($_FILES['driving_license']) {
        $driving_license = $this->upload_image($_FILES['driving_license']);
    }
    if ($_FILES['cv']) {
        $cv = $this->upload_image($_FILES['cv']);
    }

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = array(
            'name'                          => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'email'                 => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'phone'                 => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'address'               => $this->input->post('address'),
                    'sort_code'             => $this->input->post('sort_code'),
                    'bank_account'          => $this->input->post('bank_account'),
                    'passport_id'           => $passport,
                    'driving_license'       => $driving_license,
                    'cv'                    => $cv
        );

        $create = $this->model_drivers->create($data);
   }
```

here i face the problem for upload_image() how to make for each passed file to return the path?

```
public function upload_image($name = array()){
  ..................
  ...................
    $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/drivers';
    $config['file_name'] =  uniqid();
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());


        $type = explode('.', $name['name']);

        $type = $type[count($type) - 1];

        $path = $config['upload_path'].'/'.$config['file_name'].'.'.$type;
        return ($data == true) ? $path : false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pass file array and filename in the function:

```
if ($_FILES['cv']) {
        $cv = $this->upload_image($_FILES['cv'], 'cv');
    }
```

And add upload setup before `$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());` in the modified function:

```
public function upload_image($file = array(), $name = ''){
  ..................
  ...................
    $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/drivers';
    $config['file_name'] =  uniqid();
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload($name);

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $type = explode('.', $file['name']);

        $type = $type[count($type) - 1];

        $path = $config['upload_path'].'/'.$config['file_name'].'.'.$type;
        return ($data == true) ? $path : false;
```